# React + Mapbox GL: State of Array of Map Components not updating on Map Event

Tags: reactjs, mapbox-gl-js

I am attempting to create a map whereby a user can click counties on a map and the clicked counties will be highlighted like so:

[image: Photo of Highlighted Counties]

### The Problem

I have been able to create a working prototype aside from one major problem -- setting the state when a county is clicked is always based on the *original* state instead of the updated state. I'm using county FIPS ids, so if I have a list of counties like so:

`[39049, 39159]` and then I add `39023`, the updated array will be `[39049, 39159, 39023]`. However, a subsequent addition (say 39024) will change the updated array to `[39049, 39159, 39024]` instead of what I would expect: `[39049, 39159, 39023, 39024]`

Here is a JSFiddle that demonstrates the problem:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/philbirnie/vkd1nuow/21/)

And this is the pertinent code I'm using to update the county list:

```js
 componentDidMount() {
    const { lng, lat, zoom, counties } = this.state;

     ...

     map.on('click', 'counties', (e) => {
            map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';

            // Use the first found feature.
            const feature = e.features[0];

            const {FIPS} = feature.properties;
            
            let updatedCounties;
            
            if(counties.includes(FIPS)) {
                updatedCounties = counties.filter(el => el !== FIPS);
            } else {
                updatedCounties = counties.concat([FIPS]);         
            }
            
            this.setState({
                counties: updatedCounties
            });
            
            map.setFilter('counties-highlighted', [
                'in',
                'FIPS',
            ...updatedCounties
            ]);
        });
  }
```

Updating single values (like the center of the map or zoom) appear not to be a problem because it's a wholesale overwrite of the value vs modifying an array.

### Things I've tried

1. I've found that if I *mutate* the original `counties` value, it works as I would expect, but I know that is bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you "locked" your initial state values in a javascript closure, causing them to stay the same in your event handler callback, even after the state did change.

You could try to get the state from within the event handler like this:

```js
 componentDidMount() {

     map.on('click', 'counties', (e) => {
          const { lng, lat, zoom, counties } = this.state;

          // use the values that should be current here
            
     });
 }
```

Comment: How can I do this using hooks (where there is no `this` variable) ?

Comment: I just used the code from OP. He is using the local state of a React class component, hence stored in `this.state`. Using functional component instead, and hooks, this state we be probably stored in variable managed by `useState` hook. For example, `const [zoom,setZoom] = useState(1)` and then you can access the value by using the `zoom` variable. Same with other values.

Comment: yes; but what if my state has already been defined and lives "outside" the callback ? It gets "frozen" within the callback; to the value it has when the callback was defined.

Comment: You can use the variable in the callback. It's available from the outer scope. Just make sure the variable is in the dependencies array if you use `useCallback` to memoize your callback.